# Python- save pdfs from links that automatically begin download

Tags: python

I submitted an FOIA request to be able to mass download pdfs I needed for a research project and they provided me with a list of links like:

https://www.askebsa.dol.gov/BulkFOIARequest/Listings.aspx/GetFacsimile?ack_id=20190520223538P030126872271001&year=2018

I want to write a script that would automate downloading of the pdfs to my computer. The links are not .pdf links though, they just redirect to an automated download of the pdf, so I would need to click the "save" button for every one.. I was thinking I could use PyAutoGui with an Apple script to automate key presses for some programmed save button short cut.. but I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this before I go this route?

Comment: Look at this site - it might help. https://dzone.com/articles/simple-examples-of-downloading-files-using-python

Comment: @Legorooj read through, all those examples use a .pdf url or redirect to one, but thank you for trying!

Comment: Hmm. Can you give us an example link?

Comment: @Legorooj  Yes! if you click on this link, it just automatically starts to download and doesn't take you to the pdf page. All of the links are like this: https://www.askebsa.dol.gov/BulkFOIARequest/Listings.aspx/GetFacsimile?ack_id=20190520223538P030126872271001&year=2018

Comment: Umm I'm afraid that link doesn't help. I don't have a login, but I think I understand what you mean. I have an idea...

Comment: Try the `download` function from `python-wget` and

Comment: Sorry about that last comment, my PC ran out of power and shut down on me! To finish; - run it on the link you gave us and then let me know about the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having was that the link (which I did not realize you had to be logged in to click on at the time I posted this question) does not render any html and just opens the download screen that looks like this on mac:

[image]

I was trying to figure out a way to automate the clicking of the 'save' button so I could download the file links in a loop. The solution ended up being to just use selenium with the chrome driver that does not require you to click the save button.

```
url = 'https://www.askebsa.dol.gov/BulkFOIARequest/Listings.aspx/GetFacsimile?ack_id=20190520223538P030126872271001&year=2018'
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)
```

This automatically downloads like this:

[image]